# How do @value annotations work in Spring?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I've never worked with Spring before, and I've run into a configuration object that looks somewhat like this

```
public class Config {

@Value("${app.module.config1}")
private String config1;

@Value("${app.module.config2}")
private String config2

...

public String getConfig1() {
    return config1;
}

...
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here? I'm assuming this is some type of code injection, but I can't find where these values are coming from!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They allow you to direct inject a Value from a properties file (system or declared property) in the variable. Using the `util:properties` [tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html) you can add something like this in your `applicationContext.xml`

```
 <util:properties id="message" location="classpath:com/your/program/resources/message.properties" />
```

Pointing for a properties file named "message.properties" with some content:

```
 application.hello.message = Hello World!
```

And then, in your java source file, inject a direct value from this properties file using the  `@Value` annotation:

```
 @Value("#{message['application.hello.message']}")
 private String helloWorldMessage;
```

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Where can I find applicationContext.xml in the file structure? It's a pretty big bit of software.

Comment: They can be found in the `WEB-INF` directory, usually a good hint to find out the file (althought is usually named `applicationContext.xml` it could take any name) is to check out the `web.xml` file in search for the `contextConfigLocation` context-param

Answer (score 3):

> `@Value("${app.module.config1}")`

This is part of the spring expression language where the spring framework would look for `app.module.config1` JVM property from `System.getProperties()` and injects the value of that property into `config1` attribute in that class. Please see [this reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import) for more details in Spring 3.0.x and [this reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-nature) for the current docs.